# Is there a setting on an Oracle 11gR1 or R2 Client to change the data type returned by SELECT COUNT(*) from DOUBLE to LONG in an ODBC API call?

Tags: c++, oracle, count, odbc

Current C++ Application using ODBC API calling *Oracle Client 10g* (all versions), 11gR1 (v11.1.0.6) returns a LONG (4-byte integer) for
`SELECT COUNT(*) from tablename`

Change Oracle client to 11gR1 (v11.1.0.7) or higher (11.2.x.y etc) and that same statement returns a DOUBLE (8-byte floating value equivalent to oracle NUMBER data type).

Since the backend DB is the same version, there must be a client side setting (I presume) that has changed the default behaviour of this Aggregate SQL function to return a double rather than a long.  I'm hoping to find such a setting that I can either set programmatically through an ODBC API call, or in the Oracle Client configuration itself.

I even tried using `SQL CAST` to make it an `INT 
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS INT) FROM tablename`
but that still returns a `DOUBLE` (8-byte floating NUMBER).

Note: given that I use ODBC, I've written alot of generic C++ code supporting the return value as LONG, as that is how it's been for 10 years via ODBC.  I'd like to maintain that if possible without having to write ORACLE specific code within my applications.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?
There MUST be a method in the Oracle Client API that allows a setting to return all of these calls as LONG like they used to do.
RE: MAX, MIN, COUNT etc. when performed on a Long Integer / Number(10) column. I understand doing this on a Double would produce a double.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate function `count` return an `INTEGER`, it is usually referred to as `NUMBER(38,0)`.
All numeric values in an Oracle database are stored in the Oracle `NUMBER` format.

> Number of Bytes:
>
> [round((length(p)+s)/2)+1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i16209)
>
> p = precision;
>   s = 0 for positive numbers, 1 for negative numbers;
>   0 and negative infinity consume 1 byte, positive infinity consumes 2 bytes;

```
select round((length(38)+0)/2)+1 from dual; --20 bytes
```

Try this (not tested)..

```
select vsize(count(*)) from tablename;
select dump(count(*)) from tablename;
```

Data type conversion/mapping is possible with OCI [external data types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14250/oci03typ.htm).

Comment: I'm sorry, but Aggregate function COUNT returns oracle NUMBER, which is an 8-byte floating point value (double).
With a 10gR2 Oracle client on an x86 install of Oracle 11g I get
vsize=3, dump="Typ=2 Len=3: 194,3,25"
Actual count gives return value 200.
with sql*Plus v11.2.0.1 or 11.1.0.6 on a 64-bit install of Oracle 11g
I get vsize="2", dump="Typ=2 Len=2: 194,3"